# How to get Perl to loop over all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I have a Perl script with contains

```
open (FILE, '<', "$ARGV[0]") || die "Unable to open $ARGV[0]\n";

while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {
  # do stuff
}

close FILE;
```

and I would like to run this script on all `.pp` files in a directory, so I have written a wrapper script in Bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp; do
    /etc/puppet/nodes/brackets.pl $f
done
```

**Question**

Is it possible to avoid the wrapper script and have the Perl script do it instead?

Comment: The `while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)){...}` could be shortened to `while ( my $line = <FILE>){...}` as the `defined` is added for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

The `for f in ...;` translates to the Perl

- `for my $f (...) { ... }` (in the case of lists) or
- `while (my $f = ...) { ... }` (in the case of iterators).

The glob expression that you use (`/etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp`) can be evaluated inside Perl via the [`glob` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html): `glob '/etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp'`.

Together with some style improvements:

```perl
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;  # automatic error handling

while (defined(my $file = glob '/etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp')) {
  open my $fh, "<", $file;  # lexical file handles, automatic error handling

  while (defined( my $line = <$fh> )) {
    do stuff;
  }
  close $fh;
}
```

Then:

```
$ /etc/puppet/nodes/brackets.pl
```

Comment: I have a weird problem. It only get the first file that matches `.pp`. Should the `glob` line be `my @files`?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting I can’t reproduce your problem: In my test case, all the correct files are found, using my [current code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18253073/3). How do you determine that only the first file was found? When you add a `warn "opened $file\n";` after the `open`, do you only see the first filename? (Btw, you don’t have to explictly close lexical filehandles).

Comment: @amon is glob iterator usage somewhere in perldoc?

Comment: @mpapec Yes of course. In the [linked docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), in the 2nd sentence: *In scalar context, glob iterates through such filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.*

Comment: @amon You are right. I had an `exit 1` in my code that tricked me.

Comment: You can remove the `defined` from the `while` loops, as Perl will add it for you.

Answer (score 6):

This isn’t quite what you asked, but another possibility is to use `<>`:

```
while (<>) {
    my $line = $_;
    # do stuff
}
```

Then you would put the filenames on the command line, like this:

```
/etc/puppet/nodes/brackets.pl /etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp
```

Perl opens and closes each file for you. (Inside the loop, the current filename and line number are `$ARGV` and `$.` respectively.)

Comment: +1: This ***is*** the correct answer. Let the shell do the work, and allow Perl to pull off each file.

Answer (score 2):

[Jason Orendorff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253036/368630) has the right answer:

### From [Perlop (I/O Operators)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk, and any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them. Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line.

This doesn't require `opendir`. It doesn't require using `globs` or hard coding stuff in your program. This is the natural way to read in all files that are found on the command line, or piped from STDIN into the program.

With this, you could do:

```
$ myprog.pl /etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp
```

or

```
$ myprog.pl /etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp.backup
```

or even:

```
$ cat /etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp | myprog.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this documentation](http://perlmeme.org/faqs/file_io/directory_listing.html) it explains all you need to know

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '/tmp';

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
# We only want files
next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

# Use a regular expression to find files ending in .pp


   next unless ($file =~ m/\.pp$/);
open (FILE, '<', $file) || die "Unable to open $file\n";

while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {
  # do stuff
}
}

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to put all filenames to array and then use this array as parameters list to your perl method or script. Please see following code:

```
use Data::Dumper
$dirname = "/etc/puppet/nodes";
opendir ( DIR, $dirname ) || die "Error in opening dir $dirname\n";

my @files = grep {/.*\.pp/} readdir(DIR);
print Dumper(@files);

closedir(DIR);
```

Now you can pass \@files as parameter to any perl method.

Answer (score 0):

```
   my @x =   <*>;  

   foreach ( @x ) {
      chomp;
      if ( -f "$_" ) {
         print "process $_\n";  
         # do stuff
         next;
      };

    };
```

Answer (score -2):

Perl can shell out to execute system commands in various ways, the most straightforward is using backticks ``

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

my @ls = `ls /etc/puppet/nodes/*.pp`;
for my $f ( @ls ) {
   open (my $FILE, '<', $f) || die "Unable to open $f\n";

   while (defined (my $line = <$FILE>)) {
      # do stuff
   }
   close $FILE;
}
```

(Note: you should *always* `use strict;` and `use warnings;`)

Comment: It's actually a quite nice answer. I am just suprised that you launch a shell that does nothing but evaluate the glob expression and run the `ls` program to print out the filenames – separated by newlines which you do not remove. This is wrong (forgetting to `chomp`, which will cause the `open` to fail), this is bad style (`ls` is platform-dependent) and this is inefficient (launching two extra processes to emulate the Perl builtin `glob`).

Comment: In addition to what amon said, it will also break on filenames that contain whitespace.